# Python error 10042 Pusher WebSocket

Tags: python, pusher

I try to connect to Pusher Websocket API  using the following code :
https://github.com/nlsdfnbch/Pysher/

```
import pysher

# Add a logging handler so we can see the raw communication data
import logging
root = logging.getLogger()
root.setLevel(logging.INFO)
ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
root.addHandler(ch)

pusher = pysher.Pusher('de504dc5763aeef9ff52')

# We can't subscribe until we've connected, so we use a callback handler
# to subscribe when able
def connect_handler(data):
    channel = pusher.subscribe('live_trades')
    channel.bind('trade', callback)

pusher.connection.bind('pusher:connection_established', connect_handler)
pusher.connect()

while True:
    # Do other things in the meantime here...
    time.sleep(1)
```

instead of some valid response, i get this every few seconds :

> Connection: Error - [WinError 10042] An unknown, invalid, or
>   unsupported option or level was specified in a getsockopt or
>   setsockopt call Connection: Connection closed Attempting to connect
>   again in 10 seconds.

what is the problem ?

Comment: You should say something about what 'pysher' is and where to get it.  I am pretty sure that IDLE is not involved (and its tag should be removed).  To determine for sure, run your program directly with python at a command line: `python .../myprogram.py`

Comment: I ran it like you said, but same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the same error using a different library that uses websockets. I can see from your description (and link) that Pysher uses websockets.

I found (yet another) websocket client for Python that reported an issue with websockets, specifically with Python 3.6.4: [https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client/issues/370]

It references the bug in Python tracker as well [https://bugs.python.org/issue32394]

Upgrading to Python 3.6.5 worked for me. Alternatively, they suggest that upgrading to Windows 10 1703+ should work too (just for completeness; I have not verified this).